# OneLogin Notification - Track reactivation of disabled/suspended/unlicensed accounts

Tags: active-directory, html-email, onelogin

Just getting around to setting up some more detailed reporting in our OneLogin setup, and I'm not sure how to go about the title to this question.  How would I create a new notification to alert us when a user account gets reactivated in any way and by whom it was done by?

[This](https://onelogin.service-now.com/support?id=kb_article&sys_id=425e4ed4db5338901c167e77f4961990&kb_category=00b6ad30db185340d5505eea4b9619ae) has been somewhat helpful, but I feel like there are more OL database values that can and/or need to be used to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In your administration panel there is a tab for `Notifications` under the `Activity` tab. You are able to configure a email notification whenever an account is reactivated.
Upon getting the email you can log into your administration panel and view the user profile within the account to view who made the changes.

I am not an expert on the UI side of Onelogin, but I work on the engineering team. There may be an easier way to do this, but the functionality is there.